# Ros Noetic manipulator

Tags: ros, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the turtlebot waffel pi manipulator work on Noetic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391347/ros--noetic-manipulator/) by [vedgi](https://answers.ros.org/users/90034/vedgi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial for ROS Noetic has not been updated to use manipulator with waffle. Last update was melodic. Having said that if you install from source using melodic instructions it should work. Here is my suggested installation:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_manipulation.git
$ git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_manipulation_simulations.git
$ git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/open_manipulator_dependencies.git
$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-ros-control* && ros-noetic-control* && ros-noetic-moveit*
$ cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make
$ echo 'source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

To test:

```
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle_pi
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_manipulation_gazebo turtlebot3_manipulation_gazebo.launch
```

[image: image description]

It works :)

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vedgi](https://answers.ros.org/users/90034/vedgi/) on 2021-11-23**:
Nice. Thank you for the help : D